# Error en Procedimiento MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando realizar el siguiente procedimiento almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_trabajador
(
IN rut VARCHAR(12),
IN nom VARCHAR(50),
IN est VARCHAR(50),
IN sueldo INT(11)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO trabajadores
(
rut,
nombre,
estado,
sueldo_base
) 
VALUES
(
rut,
nom,
est,
sueldo
);
END
```

Pero me da este error  que sería el `);`

> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 22

Comment: antes del create procedure agrega `DELIMITER $$`
y en el `END $$`

Comment: deberias de cambiar los parametros de entrada diferente puede que este alli el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, MySQL considera que el punto y coma es un delimitador. Si no redifines eso, MySQL considera que `);` es el final de tu procedimiento.

Por eso, usualmente debes rodear la definición de tu procedimiento de esta manera:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_trabajador
(
IN rut VARCHAR(12),
IN nom VARCHAR(50),
IN est VARCHAR(50),
IN sueldo INT(11)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO trabajadores
(
rut,
nombre,
estado,
sueldo_base
) 
VALUES
(
rut,
nom,
est,
sueldo
);
END//

delimiter ;
```